# How to get file name in text box on selection (Not like c:/fake path/)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want is as soon I choose a file in a file `input` I want to get the file name in text box named `file_name` without any click or submit button. I could not figure out the code for it.

```
<input type="text" name="file_name" id="file_name" class="cfGradient inputField">
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" onchange="document.getElementById('file_name').value = this.value">
```

When I am selecting any file from my E drive the output was `c:/fake path/selected file` but I need the original path of the selected file. Please provide me the code and idea.

Comment: You can't. This is a security measure of all modern browsers (although the `c:/fake path` is intrinsic to IE, other browsers just give you the file name).

Comment: Any possibilities in Jquery ?

Comment: No. The browsers do their best to prevent any knowledge of the local file system through JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: below code working fine in IE and Firefox not in chrome.Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this.

```
<input type="file" name="file_name" id="file_name" class="cfGradient inputField">

<script type="text/javascript">
function getFilePath(){
     $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
         var filePath=$('#file_name').val(); 
     });
}
</script>
```

hope this will help you thanx.

Comment: i need full file path

Comment: working fine firefox and IE but not in chrome. Any idea ?